# I need help understanding how to assign roman numerals to a key as well as how to do a melodic analysis

Tags: chords, melody, analysis, roman-numerals

Here is the link to the questions:

https://scontent.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/s2048x2048/76767498_631590154044645_5429312693389492224_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=xzP3WM_WkZMAQmsld8rZQ8kb20ASCOrOSCyvGWN0pnvYS5Q0eX7tCdXZg&_nc_ht=scontent.fybz2-1.fna&oh=dcfbf15fad574a77425df2f45d7bf38e&oe=5E7EAB39

Can someone explain how to figure out what the roman numerals are for the underlined chords? 
Also, how do I know which notes to look at when analyzing the melody when labelling it as passing tone, suspension, etc (do I look at the whole chord+melody until the next chord+melody)?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Did you look up the related questions on the right corner of this site? 1. you missed in your marks below the flats! 2nd. You don't have to analyze the passing and short changing tones. 3. Is this a homework? (SE doesn't do your homework ...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework/quiz. You will find the answers by reading the chapter and asking your teacher. If you have read the material, explain what is confusing you in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start.

---

First, identify the key:

```
You have already found the key to be Eb major.
```

---

Then, write the notes in the key/scale:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1
    Eb F  G  Ab Bb C  D  Eb
```

---

Now, find the primary and secondary triad chords of the scale:

```
    I     Eb G  Bb  
    ii    F  Ab C  
    iii   G  Bb D 
    IV    Ab C  Eb  
    V     Bb D  F  
    vi    C  Eb G
    vii°  D  F  Ab
```

---

Now match the triads with the chords.

---

(Sorry I can't help with figured bass)

Comment: what if the there are two of the same notes in one chord? ex D Bflat D

Comment: Doubling a note in a chord is okay, but it makes it a bit harder to identify which chord it is.  

The first and third notes (first two columns of my table) in the chords are more important than the fifth (third column).  

So, with D, Bflat, D, it is a form the V chord.

Answer (score 1):

An important point to remember when writing out the chord tones is to designate which tones include accidentals. Without the accidentals, we're actually talking about completely different chords and it makes it more difficult to properly analyze. If you refer back to the key signature, it will tell you which notes in the scale are to be flatted or sharped and you will be able to sort these things out more accurately. I hope this helps.

Comment: By way of explanation about my use of the words flatted and sharped, I'm referring to the addition of a flat sign or a sharp sign to the particular note, rather than to the actual raising in pitch or reducing in pitch of a scale tone. I find changing my wording around sometimes alters the meaning of the point I'm attempting to make. If you choose to edit my answer, please don't change the meaning. Thank you.